# Specifying SDKROOT's for different architectures on iOS

Tags: ios, xcodebuild

I've read this [post](https://medium.com/@Roman_Dzieciol/building-fat-binaries-in-xcode-without-lipo-scripts-d33de2883420) and I've managed to achieve fat builds without using a script. My next step is to try and do this using the terminal to produce a fat binary.

In the post the author states to add the following to the project file:

```
SDKROOT = iphoneos
SDKROOT[arch=i386] = $(CORRESPONDING_SIMULATOR_SDK_NAME)
SDKROOT[arch=x86_64] = $(CORRESPONDING_SIMULATOR_SDK_NAME)
```

Given that I can make a fat binary from the build settings in the project file, the assumption is that I can do this from the terminal. My issue lies in how to specify the `SDKROOT[arch=i386]` and `SDKROOT[arch=x86_64]` in terminal. I've tried varying combinations with no luck. Here is one of the many tried attempts at it:

```
xcodebuild clean analyze ARCHS='arm64 armv7 i386 x86_64' SDKROOT='iphoneos' SDKROOT[arch=i386] = 'iphonesimulator12.1' SDKROOT[arch=x86_64] = 'iphonesimulator12.1'


xcodebuild clean analyze ARCHS='arm64 armv7 i386 x86_64' SDKROOT='iphoneos iphonesimulator12.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify it this way. Each SDKROOT needs to map to the SDKROOT property in the SDKs Info.pist (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Info.plist in this example). In the iPhoneSimulator SDK this property is set to: iphonesimulator. So you have the ARCHS variable set correctly (though I am suspect of the armv7 and arm64 ARCHS as the SDK in an Intel platform binary, you might need to remove those, my memory is a bit jumbled on this point).

But you can only specify one SDKROOT per xcodebuild invocation. Your first line is nearly correct, but I think should be:

xcodebuild clean analyze ARCHS='arm64 armv7 i386 x86_64' SDKROOT='iphonesimulator'